# Automatically insert the login name when new row created in postgres

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres 10, is it possible to automatically insert the name of the login role when creating a new row?

i.e. I'm already using a timestamp to track the date that a row was created. It would also be useful to see which user created the row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just make the column's default `session_user`. (It's a pseudo-variable, not a function call).

If you want to prevent a user from overriding it, you should also make sure to `GRANT` write permissions to the table on a per-column basis, not to the table as a whole, and make sure the regular operating user is not the table owner.

Or alternately, have a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger that sets `NEW.the_column := session_user`.